# Javascript import/export csv file on IE9 and send to controller

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with generating and importing csv file by my browser. Generates the file based on the data contained in the database. Export works but when importing I don't get data but some strange signs. below I send photos.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYJsr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkspl.png)

Comment: _“below I send photos”_ - please don’t; code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in _text form_. Please go read [ask], and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof FormData == "undefined") {
            var file = $("#file");
            var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var filePath = file[0].value;
            var objFile = objFSO.getFile(filePath);
            var iStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1, false);
            var value = iStream.ReadAll();
            iStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") { 
            var oWin = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");                
            oWin.document.write('sep=,\r\n' + CSV);
            oWin.document.close();
            oWin.document.save = "csv";
            oWin.document.charset = "UTF-8";
             var pathways = oWin.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, "AuxPt.csv");

            oWin.close();
```